# Font settings for strings in java

Tags: java, string, fonts, properties, console

Can I set font properties for a string in java.

Comment: The question lacks the information whether you're using swing, awt, swt or something else - even the console could be meant.

Comment: I added 'console' to the tags.

Answer (score 11):

Font properties are set on the Font object in the GUI object that you are using (`JLabel`, etc), not on the `String` itself.

EDIT:

If you want to add formatting to your console, you will have to embed the formatting within the `String` itself. In order to get my output to be bold, I needed to do the following:

```
 System.out.println((char)27 +"[1m testing bold");
```

The `(char) 27` is an escape sequence, the `[` is followed by a set of `;` separated values for different formatting types (see below), followed by an `m`.  You will need to play around with this.  On my Mac, the command prompt continued in bold as I didnt reset to normal (`[0m`) before I exited.

This info, by the way, was lifted from [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t143949-text-color-in-windows-console.html).
some attributes:

```
0 Normal (clear all)
1 bold
2 dim
4 underline
5 blink
7 reverse
8 blank
9 overstrike
22 normal intensity (cancel bold and blank)
24 underline off
25 blink off
27 reverse off
28 blank off
29 overstrike off
30 black
31 red
32 green
33 yellow
34 blue
35 magenta
36 cyan
37 white
40 black background
41 red background
42 green background
```

Comment: @akf : So I could not display a string with font settings applied. Right?

Comment: You can apply the font settings on the `JLabel` or `JButton` or whatever GUI object (use  `myLabel.setFont(myLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD))` or something similar), and the `String` will be displayed with the particular attributed (bold, italic, etc).

Comment: @akf : Thanks for your response. Here I do not use any swing components. I need to apply the properties to a string and just display it on the console.

Comment: Those ansicodes will work in Linux - at least every flavor I tried out in the last 13 years. But on windows, it will not work out of the box, you will need 'ansi.sys' and do some configuration to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

A String doesn't have a font, as it's completely separate from any way to display it.
Fonts are related to the user interface components you're using to present the String to your users, how to set it would depend on those user interface components.

Comment: Sometimes it has: `new JLabel ("<html>foo<b>bold bar</b>font</html>")`

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to escape "\033" [here](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-theory-questions/18443-how-make-console-output-bold.html)

Also, I wanted the official attributes list in regards to "akf's attribute chart which I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) - referenced in the "SGR (Select Graphic Rendition) parameters" table

I would like to add that neither of these worked for me in eclipse console output.  I take it that is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AttributedString`. Here is some examples: [JavaDocExamples](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/text/AttributedString/addAttribute%28Attribute%20attribute,Object%20value%29.html)

```
Font font = new Font("LucidaSans", Font.PLAIN, 14);
AttributedString messageAS = new AttributedString(textMessage);
...
messageAS.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font);
AttributedCharacterIterator messageIterator = messageAS.getIterator();
FontRenderContext messageFRC = graphics2D.getFontRenderContext();
LineBreakMeasurer messageLBM = new LineBreakMeasurer(messageIterator, messageFRC);
```

Comment: Please add an example to this answer. The linked examples might go away.