# How to print underlined string in console output in java

Tags: java, string

I want to know if there is any way to print the underlined text on console using java String class.

Comment: why not System.out.println(/*..*/);

Comment: There already is an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062458/font-settings-for-strings-in-java

Comment: PrP3; that's helpful - I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: None of this will work in Windows command prompt. It's specific to full-fledged terminal emulators (the norm on *nixes, including Mac).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only rely on how the String is interpreted by your console. For example, in `bash`, you can do something like inserting your string between escape sequences `\033[1m` and `\033[0m` (for **bold**):

```
\033[1mInsert your String here\033[0m
```

You should read the documentation of your favorite console.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a look at the `tput` command as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924697/how-does-one-output-bold-text-in-bash#2924755), but it will make your code a bit unreadable as it will look like this

```
System.out.println("...")
// execute tput
System.out.println("underlined text")
// execute tput
System.out.println("...")
```

Also, [this page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html) may help

Notice I'm assuming you aim for bash like terminal

Answer (score 2):

I used Netbeans IDE v12.0

```
String txt="Welcome Back";
String utxt = String.join("\u0332",n.split("",-1));
System.out.println(utxt);
```

Output

```sh
W̲e̲l̲c̲o̲m̲e̲ ̲B̲a̲c̲k̲
```

[result in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aVQx.png)

Answer (score -3):

On my IDE you can also use like the below Mentioned :

```
System.out.println("Underlined Text");
System.out.println("_______________")
```

Comment: I find this rather funny.