# How to print an underlined string in java with eclipse

Tags: java, string, printing, underscore.js, underline

```
S = "hello"

System.out.print(s)
```

I've also tried:

```
System.out.println("\033[4mhello\033[0m");
```

This prints out `[4mhello[0m`

I'm stuck on how to print hello underlined. I search everywhere but got no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354875/how-to-print-underlined-string-in-console-output-in-java

This may help you.

Comment: it depends on which 'terminal' you are using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print underlined string in console output in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354875/how-to-print-underlined-string-in-console-output-in-java)

Comment: Does this work? `System.out.println("h͟e͟l͟l͟o͟");`

Answer (score 1):

use ANSI codes.

like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\033[4;2m" + "Hello World");
    }
}
```

note:

ANSI-coded strings wont work in windows terminal.