# Eclipse console styling

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a way to print italics out of the Eclipse console. So that some variation of:

```
System.out.println((Some code)"Hello World");
```

Outputs:

*Hello* World

Is this even possible?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Did you try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062458/font-settings-for-strings-in-java

Comment: This particular method doesn't seem to be working for me, escape sequences are different on my computer I think.

Comment: @mdewitt those styles are for the windows console and don't seem to work in the eclipse console

Comment: Depends on your platform.  If it supports the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), then there's a chance.

Comment: @mdewitt wait, there seems to be an eclipse plugin to use those codes in eclipse, so it might still be useful  http://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options available to you with this, but first off, I'll make it clear that this is *not* a default Java ability. It depends entirely on the Operating System and the output console you are using (Eclipse, Terminal, Command, etc).

## JCurses

You can use the [JCurses Library](http://javacurses.sourceforge.net/) to give you additional functions over the default console window. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077406/learn-java/a-splash-of-text-color-with-your-java.html) that might help you.

## ANSI Escape Sequences

I found a link [here](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-theory-questions/18443-how-make-console-output-bold.html#post78703) that uses ANSI Escape Sequences to modify the text, and ran the code myself to double-check it worked fine. It certainly changed the font, and there are some escape sequences listed [here](http://www.javaservletsjspweb.in/2013/06/coloring-java-output-on-console.html) that might help you.

I believe italics should be `System.out.println("\030[3mHello World!\030[0m");`