# How to print an String variable as italicized text

Tags: java, italics, text-styling

I have the following statements inside my class:

```
String myName = "Joe";
System.out.println("My name is " +myName);
```

I need the value on the variable `myName` to be printed as *italic* text.

Comment: Well does your console *support* italicized text? We have no idea where you're even trying to run it. You should normally just consider the console as a simple console output device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132541/eclipse-console-styling    This link will help you in this regard. System.out.println("\030[3mMy name is\030[0m");

Comment: this is a class exercise.

Comment: Are you trying to apply style in the console output or you are trying to use it with swing or JSP?

Comment: @Hurix That's not going to work in general.  For instance, in my eclipse console it just prints out garbage characters.

Comment: I'm using netBeans to code in java and my goal is to be able to see the variable content in italic when I hit the run button. I don't know if I have to import some library first in order to accomplish this.

Comment: yes, I need it to be shown in the console output

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
System.out.println("\033[3mText goes here\033[0m");
```

Which will output italic text if your console supports it. You can use `[1m` for bold, etc. Play around with the different values of `[`*n*`m`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Foo
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("myFile.html"));
out.println("<u><i>my output</i></u>");
out.flush();
out.close();
}
}
```

Comment: It should be in the console.