# Write a string in Eclipse console in Bold?

Tags: java

I would like to write a String in Eclipse Console in Bold (just the "test.txt") ...

```
System.out.println("the name of the file is ? test.txt");
```

---

Please this solution [Font settings for strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062458/font-settings-for-strings-in-java) is not working !

When I do : `System.out.println((char)27 +"[1m testing bold");`

I get : `[1m testing bold`

---

I am using Java-8u40 so Eclipse Luna is using Javaw.exe ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is highly dependent on the console. With the one in Eclipse you won't be able to display bold text.

An easier way to display different types of fonts is to use Swing's JTextArea and use [HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) formatting.

Comment: Not possible with the Eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such information sent to console, you can use some libraries or plugins to achieve that in a more reliable way, like:

http://marian.schedenig.name/projects/grep-console/

Comment: not working on Java Eclipse Console and the variable activateBold should be **static**.

Comment: Static? Maybe I was refering to a singleton class or utility class and it would be pointless to have a static variable like that one if I'm not going to use it outside the object.