# How to make string value in bold in java?

Tags: java, string

I want a string value to be bold in color

For example

```
String value = "Hello World";
System.out.print(value);
```

Output should be

**Hello World**

I want it in clean java code only not using swing or applet code. Canyone help me to solve this one?

Comment: [This is one way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062458/font-settings-for-strings-in-java), assuming you mean printing to a standard Windows or Linux console.

Comment: please refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109678/java-print-in-bold

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is highly system dependent. If your system supports ANSI, then I suppose you could do something like this:

```
String value = (char)27 + "[1mHello World!";
System.out.print(value);
```

although I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I don't think java supports `\x`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in front of value in print: "\u001B[1m"

Here is how the code should look like:

```
String value = "Hello World"; 
System.out.print("\u001B[1m" + value);
```